Unable to transfer Spl Token in Solidity via CPI in anchor
import "solana";
import "./spl_token_minter.sol";
function transferTokensFromUserToContract(address user, uint256 amount, address signerAccount) internal {
        uint64 amount64 = uint64(amount);
        AccountMeta[3] metas = [
            AccountMeta({pubkey: user, is_writable: false, is_signer: false}), // User's token account
            AccountMeta({pubkey: contractTokenAccount, is_writable: false, is_signer: false}), // Contract's token account
            AccountMeta({pubkey: signerAccount, is_writable: true, is_signer: true}) // SplTokenMinter program
        ];

        spl_token_minter.transferTokens{accounts: metas}( amount64 );
    }

Trying to transfer token in my Solidity Smart contract via CPI call(creating and importing the interface generated of the spl file https://solang.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.3/targets/solana.html#calling-anchor-programs-from-solidity as stated in official docs )in anchor, all but the token balances are unchanged.
Token Transfer function implemented in spltokenMinter file:
    @mutableAccount(from) // token account to transfer from
    @mutableAccount(to) // token account to transfer to
    @mutableSigner(owner)
    function transferTokens(
        uint64 amount // amount to transfer
    ) external {
        print("inside the transfer token function");
        SplToken.transfer(
            tx.accounts.from.key, 
            tx.accounts.to.key, 
            tx.accounts.owner.key, 
            amount
        );
    }

